# What is the difference between: "hide posts" and "ignore this user (everywhere)" in chatrooms?

Tags: discussion

I don't see any difference between:

**Actions**

"hide posts"

and

"ignore this user  (everywhere)"

Is there any difference in their scope and if so what is it?

Comment: Does the "everywhere" include all other chatrooms also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This was asked & answered Mother Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156160/in-chat-what-is-the-difference-between-hide-posts-and-ignore-this-user). Direct copy-pasta of (the relevant portion of) their answer:

> "Hide posts" just hides them for that 'session' (i.e. you refresh and they are back!)
>
> "Ignore this user everywhere" is persistent across rooms / sessions.

Both actions will hide the user; clicking "show posts" will undo both actions. So the difference is the persistence. The latter, of course, requiring you to select them back whereas the former will do it for your next browser refresh.

Comment: Mmmmm, I think I'll have some copy-pasta for dinner!